# Prove the existence of the following

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$.  Prove that for every subspace of $V$, $W$, there exists a subspace $U$, such that $W+U=V$ and $W \cap U= \left\{ \mathbb{O}_V \right\}$

Where $\mathbb{O}_V$ is the zero vector for $V$.

I know such a space exists.  It is called the orthogonal compliment of W, $W^\perp$, but we haven't developed the concept of orthogonality in my class yet.  Can I do this generally?

Comment: Choose a basis for $W$, extend to a basis of $V$, let $U$ be the span of the new guys.

Comment: How much can you use? For e.g., there is a result that says that any linearly independent set in $V$ can be extended to a basis of $V$. Then, you can start with a basis of $U$ and extend it via the result to a basis of $V$; the 'extension' basis elements form a basis for a complement of $W$ in $V$, as you can check.

Comment: Oh, that was so simple!  We actually talked about that just last class.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly prove it for finite dimensional spaces. Choose a basis for $W$, extend it to a basis for $V$, and then $W^\perp$ is the span of the basis elements that are not in $W$. For an arbitrary vector space, I believe you need some form of Choice.